# Oracle 12c AMM is disabled when memory_max_target = memory_target =0

Tags: oracle

With command：SHOW PARAMETER TARGET I get result below.
According to [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/memory003.htm#ADMIN11200), *memory_max_target* and *memory_target* is default value 0.
For some reason, EM can not be installed, so I can't verify AMM status.
I wanna to verify if AMM is disabled when *memory_max_target* = *memory_target* =0

```
NAME                                               TYPE        VALUE                                                                                                
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
archive_lag_target                                 integer     0                                                                                                    
db_big_table_cache_percent_target                  string      0                                                                                                    
db_flashback_retention_target                      integer     1440                                                                                                 
fast_start_io_target                               integer     0                                                                                                    
fast_start_mttr_target                             integer     0                                                                                                    
memory_max_target                                  big integer 0                                                                                                    
memory_target                                      big integer 0                                                                                                    
parallel_servers_target                            integer     64                                                                                                   
pga_aggregate_target                               big integer 816M                                                                                                 
sga_target                                         big integer 2448M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic memory management can be enabled in two "modes" so to speak.

Either you want to have whole memory managed by Oracle or you will specify PGA and SGA and let Oracle manage the SGA pools by itself.

Both these modes are AMM.

In your case you have AMM set up to handle PGA and SGA separatelly.

- To setup AMM taking over whole memory, you need to set `MEMORY_TARGET = XXX`
- To setup AMM to manage PGA and SGA, you need to set `MEMORY_TARGET = 0; PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET = XXX; SGA_TARGET = XXX;`
- To disable AMM, you have to setup all pools manually and `MEMORY_TARGET, SGA_TARGET, PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET` need to be set to `= 0`.

Manual pools parameters that are mandatory, are:

```
DB_CACHE_SIZE
JAVA_POOL_SIZE
LARGE_POOL_SIZE
SHARED_POOL_SIZE
PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET
```

More info on this topic can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-E6784230-0A0C-443D-8537-36FFA08A7E75.htm#ADMQS12039